# SQL Server : select groups with latest updated reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a select query to list ReportGroups according to last reports updated in them.

for example, this query lists report groups with maximum creation date of it's reports:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT rg.ReportGroupID
FROM Report.ReportGroups as rg
INNER JOIN Report.Reports as r ON rg.ReportGroupID = r.ReportGroupID
GROUP BY rg.ReportGroupID
ORDER BY MAX(CreateDate) DESC
```

Output:

```
20|2015-02-28
8 |2015-02-17
1 |2015-02-10
36|2015-01-11
25|2014-12-20
18|2014-12-16
```

Now, I need all ReportGroup columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Report.ReportGroups 
WHERE ReportGroupID IN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT rg.ReportGroupID
    FROM Report.ReportGroups as rg
    INNER JOIN Report.Reports as r ON rg.ReportGroupID = r.ReportGroupID
    GROUP BY rg.ReportGroupID
    ORDER BY MAX(CreateDate) DESC
)
```

Output:

```
1 |Group 1
8 |Group 8
18|Group 18
20|Group 20
25|Group 25
36|Group 36
```

but this query's result is not ordered like the previous query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with outer apply:

```
SELECT
  rg.*
FROM 
  Report.ReportGroups as rg
  outer apply (
    select top 1 r.CreateDate 
    from Report.Reports as r
    where rg.ReportGroupID = r.ReportGroupID
    order by r.CreateDate DESC
  ) r
ORDER BY 
    r.CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks it' correct, i didn't know about "outer apply", what is it and which version of sql server support that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. Changed to join based selection and ordered by inner (max) createdate.

```
SELECT rg1.* 
FROM Report.ReportGroups rg1
JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT rg.ReportGroupID, MAX(CreateDate) createdate
    FROM Report.ReportGroups as rg
    INNER JOIN Report.Reports as r ON rg.ReportGroupID = r.ReportGroupID
    GROUP BY rg.ReportGroupID
    ORDER BY MAX(CreateDate) DESC
) trg ON rg1.ReportGroupID = trg.ReportGroupID
ORDER BY trg.createdate;
```